# Sonarqube integration with Gitlab CI - SonarQube server can not be reached

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've been searching for answers to this issue but I couldn't find a solution for me.

I'm trying to use sonarqube with Gitlab CI. I'm really new to this things.

So far, I could install a docker image of sonarqube and run it locally with success. However, when I'm trying to make it work with gitlab CI, I'm getting "SonarQube server [192.168.10.5:9000] can not be reached". 192.168.10.5 is my IP and 9000 the port that I'm using.

I'm working in a java 8 - maven project.

Here's the plugin that I used in my pom.xml for sonarqube:

```xml
...
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.0.905</version>
</plugin>
...
```

In my .m2/settings.xml I have this profile:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>sonar</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <sonar.host.url>http://192.168.10.5:9000</sonar.host.url>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

And here is my gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-8

variables:
   SONAR_TOKEN: "myUserToken"
   SONAR_HOST_URL: "192.168.10.5:9000"
   GIT_DEPTH: 0

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

stages:
  - quality_test
  - build

quality_test:
  stage: quality_test
  script:
      - mvn pmd:check 
      - mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN -DskipTests
  allow_failure: true

build:
  stage: build
  script:
      - mvn package -DskipTests
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/com.jar
```

When I push to gitlab the pipeline "pass" with "warnings":

```
[INFO] User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
[ERROR] SonarQube server [192.168.10.5:9000] can not be reached
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.785 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-16T20:16:23Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project project: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: unexpected url: 192.168.10.5:9000/batch/index -> [Help 1]
```

I understand that it couldn't reach the server that I specified with "192.168.10.5:9000", where 192.168.10.5 is my IP. I tried with localhost:9000 with the same result.

The gitlab ci runner isn't executing locally.

I'm really stuck on this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Apologies in advance, it's my first post and english isn't my native language.

Comment: Can the server running gitlab reach 192.168.10.5 at all? It looks like you might just be missing the http:// in the SONAR_HOST_URL.

Comment: I've fixed it and it throws "connect time out" instead of "unexpected url". So, I think that you're right. The server running gitlab can not reach my ip. I don't really know how to deal with it, but at least it's a different problem now. Thank you!